# Insert HTML or append Child onClick, and remove from previous clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of div elements inside a container, `.div-to-hide` is displayed by default whilst `.div-to-show` is hidden.

When I click in .set, `.div-to-hide` should hide and `.div-to-show` should be visible. Next click should return the previous clicked element to its default state.

I need to display to buttons on click inside on `.div-to-show`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="set">
    <div class="div-to-hide">Some text</div>
    <div class="div-to-show"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="div-to-hide">Some text</div>
    <div class="div-to-show"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="div-to-hide">Some text</div>
    <div class="div-to-show"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have this:

```
let lastClicked;
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this == lastClicked) {
    lastClicked = '';
    $('.div-to-hide').show();
    $(this).children('.div-to-hide').hide();
  } else {
    lastClicked = this;
    $('.div-to-hide').hide();
    $(this).children('.div-to-hide').show();
    $(this).children('.div-to-show').hide();
  }
});
```

Can't get it to work properly tho.. I don't know what I am missing...

Any help is deeply appreciated!

UPDATE: got it working! Thanks everyone!

Comment: `$('.contaiiner')` typo?

Comment: also missing a bracket on `</div`

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif If the error is a typo, editing the question to fix the typo isn't really appropriate.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need to show the "div-to-show" class only on the last .set clicked?

Answer (score 2):

First, you are not using [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) (second parameter on the $.on() function) to define the `.set` element as your `this` inside the function.

If I understood correctly, you want to show the elements on the last one clicked and hide the rest. You don't really need to know which one you last clicked to do that

```
$('.container').on('click', '.set', function (e) {
    // Now "this" is the clicked .set element
    var $this = $(this);
    // We'll get the children of .set we want to manipulate
    var $div_to_hide = $this.find(".div-to-hide");
    var $div_to_show = $this.find(".div-to-show");

    // If it's already visible, there's no need to do anything
    if ($div_to_show.is(":visible")) {
        $div_to_hide.show();
        $div_to_show.hide();
    }

    // Now we get the other .sets 
    var $other_sets = $this.siblings(".set");

    // This second way works for more complex hierarchies. Uncomment if you need it
    // var $other_sets = $this.closest(".container").find(".set").not(this);

    // We reset ALL af them
    $other_sets.find(".div-to-show").hide();
    $other_sets.find(".div-to-hide").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using class toggling instead.

```
$('.set').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.set').removeClass('hidden-child');
  $(this).addClass('hidden-child');
});
```

css:

```
.hidden-child .div-to-hide, .div-to-show {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-child .div-to-show, .div-to-hide {
  display: block;
}
```

This will make your code easier to reason about, and lets css control the display (style) rules.

Edit: changed class name for clarity; expanded explanation; corrected answer to conform to question

Comment: why to add a class and then use toggleClass instead of just $.toggle()? Why go the extra mile?

Comment: By toggling the class on the top level element, you can avoid having to find and manipulate the children one by one. It makes it easier to follow your logic.

Comment: It should alternate, check the css rules.

Comment: Ahhhh, you're using the more specific one to override.  I see

Comment: The global-ness is intended. It is a rule that should be overwritten when the more specific .hidden-child rule applies. Edit: NINJA'd

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of  ***[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)*** jQuery to hide and show other divs and ***[toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)*** jQuery to show and hide itself and also you will need to set `click()` event on `.set`, not in `.container`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.set', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.hide').toggle();
  $(this).find('.show').toggle();
  $(this).siblings('.set').find('.hide').show();
  $(this).siblings('.set').find('.show').hide();
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: none;
}

.set div {
  padding: 10px;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="set">
    <div class="hide">1 Hide</div>
    <div class="show">1 Show</div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="hide">2 Hide</div>
    <div class="show">2 Show</div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="hide">3 Hide</div>
    <div class="show">3 Show</div>
  </div>
</div>
```